# How can C# Enums be improved

Tags: c#, validation, enums

If I create an enum like this

```
public enum ImportType
{
   Direct,
   Indirect,
   InBond
}
```

and I have a method that takes an ImportType as parameter as follows

```
public bool ProcessValidImport(ImportType type)
{
    // Process ImportType variable here
}
```

I can go and call the method as follows

```
bool blnProcessed = ProcessValidImport((ImportType)7);
```

But the `ImportType` variable value of `7` passed in to the method is not valid at all because any integer will work if cast. The enum defaults to an int type, so what is the best way to validate that an enum in this case is in fact a valid `ImportType`.

Comment: You can [test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Are you looking for this ProcessValidImport(ImportType.Direct);?

Comment: I just wouldn't use them.... They're useful for flags, like `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`, but in my opinion if you use them in control flow then you will almost always not be following open closed.

Comment: @CallumLinington would using validation like this below 'Enum.IsDefined'  not ensure that the internal workings of the class remains unmodified? Thereby maintaining open closed principal? Sorry, I'm a newbie, so I genuinely don't know. I know that I can make the class "Open" by extending it via inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but you can validate enum easily using:

```
int value = 7;
bool isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof (ImportType), value);
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I tested it and it works 100%. Thank you very much!